# Is there a way to remove the many to many list properties from related table in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a way to remove the many-to-many relationship tables from the mapped entities in EF Core.
The below code is an example and does not include the ModeblBuilder mapping.  I just want to know if I can remove the commented sections and have it work please.

```
public class User
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Role> { get; set; } // <- remove this
} 

public class Role
{
     public int RoleId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<User> { get; set; } // <-- remove this
}

public class UserRole
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public User User { get; set; }

     public int RoleId { get; set; }
     public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove them as long as you setup the mapping. What does your mapping look like? Where are you running into a problem?

Comment: Removing them means you won't be able to navigate from Role to User or vice versa. Are you *sure* that's what you want?

Comment: The correct term is "navigation property". And yes, you can remove them, and that don't even need fluent configuration or data annotations. Just make sure the  link entity (table) is registered in the model (via public `DbSet` or fluently). Everything you need to know is explained in [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) section of EF Core documentation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I don't mind losing that functionality to remove the relationship form the model itself but thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the mapping to your user role entity and it will work.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
  //... other mapping
  .HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany()
  .HasOne(x => x.Role).WithMany()
```

As pointed out in the comments, this isn't really needed since everything should work by convention based on your naming. If you don't follow the naming conventions, this will be needed.

Comment: This is not needed as well.

Comment: That's true, it should work by convention with the current naming.